# I want my reference list numbering in square bracket numbering format with vancouver style in word 2010. reference is looking like [1] 1. bla bla

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles, numbering, bibliography, citations

I want use the Vancouver style for my research article. i have installed vancouver.xsl file and all the citations within the text and bibliography are appearing correctly.
but the bibliography list starts with 1. and I want it [1]. I have introduced square bracket format [1]in numbering, but then it looks [1] 1. bla [2] 2 blabla

please guide me for Vancouver style what to edit to get [1] bla likewise